# I fail to understand why I can't PUT values inside an existing table in a database ;/

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, node-postgres

I have a precreated table in a database which I want to insert values into from the frontend (i.e by the user) but for some reason the code I wrote fails to achieve what I am seeking :/

I'm still a beginner so be harsh on me so that I learn by remembering what I faced here.

Here is the server side of the code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// input values
app.put("/admin/staff", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {adminstration} = await req.body;
        // contains the admin table details to be added
        const newadminstration = await pool.query("INSERT INTO adminstration (adminstration) VALUES ($1) RETURNING *", [adminstration]);
        res.json(newadminstration.rows[0]);
        console.log(newadminstration)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});
app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("server is running on port 5000")
});
```

here is the the frontend side of the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import {  Input} from '@mui/material';

export default function Adminfun() { 
    const [adminstration, setadminstration] = useState({admin_name:"", admin_email:"", admin_password:""});
const bbb= async (e) => {
        e.preventdefault();
        try {

            const body = { adminstration };
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/admin/staff", {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            });
            console.log(response)
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message)
        } 
    }; return (
    <Box
    component="form"
    sx={{
      '& > :not(style)': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },
    }}
    noValidate
    autoComplete="off">
        <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Name" variant="outlined" value={adminstration.admin_name} 
        onChange={(Event) => 
            {const newAdminstration = {...adminstration};
            newAdminstration.admin_name = Event.target.value;
            setadminstration(newAdminstration)}}/>
             {/* {setadminstration({...adminstration, admin_name: Event.target.value})}}/> */}
        <TextField id="filled-basic" label="Email" variant="filled" value={adminstration.admin_email} 
        onChange={(Event) =>
           {setadminstration({...adminstration, admin_email: Event.target.value})}}/>
        <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Password" variant="standard" value={adminstration.admin_password} 
        onChange={(Event) => 
            {const newAdminstration = {...adminstration};
            newAdminstration.admin_password = Event.target.value;
            setadminstration(newAdminstration)}}/>
    <br></br>
    <Input type='submit' onSubmit={bbb} >Submit</Input>
   </Box>)
};
```

node js for the backend, postgresql database, react for the frontend.

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: I don't see where you `commit` the transaction.

Comment: What is the problem ? Is it a database issue ? front end ? or back end issue ? Write debug statements at different points in the code and troubleshoot to isolate these.

Comment: From here [pool](https://node-postgres.com/apis/pool): *Do not use pool.query if you are using a transaction. ... For more info please read transactions*. [Transactions](https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions). That would explain your issue.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you very much Sir. I'll look into it In Sha Allah

Comment: He's not using a transaction. What is the SQL schema? Looks like your trying to directly insert JSON?

Comment: @leitning Thank you. I managed by the blessings of my lord to handle the request issue however it now only works in insomnia not through the react app, I tried finding the issue but I couldn't /:

Comment: You still have not said what the issue is.  Is there an error thrown? Does the inserted value not show up in the database? What does the Postgres log show when you attempt the INSERT? **Add answers to your question as an update**.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver actually the issue had nothing to do with transactions but like @ leitning pointed out, I had to further deconstruct the json object ... I don't know if this was a silly mistake from my side^^

Comment: It would have had something to do with transactions when you properly dealt with the JSON and then found the record was not being saved.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you sir. I'm still new to this, so mind my ignorance of not being capable to understand your profound insights. any tutorials you suggest for further learning?

Comment: Any basic SQL book/tutorial. In Postgres docs [Transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html).  For your node-postgres code [Transactions](https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I really appreciate the sincere care you gave to this small question of mine, and that is something very rare. Again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Following my senior - @AdrianKlaver - commands I have managed to successfully solve the issue although another was found -and for that I posted a separate question- and here is the updated code:

```
app.put("/admin/staff", async (req, res) => {
    const client = await pool.connect()
    try {
        await client.query('BEGIN')
        console.log(req.body)
        const {adminstration } = await req.body
        const {admin_name, admin_email, admin_password} = adminstration
        await client.query("INSERT INTO adminstration (admin_name, admin_email, admin_password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *", [admin_name, admin_email, admin_password]);
        await client.query('COMMIT')
        return res.status(201).send("ok")
    }
        catch (err) {
        await client.query('ROLLBACK')
        throw err
        // console.error(err.message);
    } finally {
        client.release()
    }
});
```

Upon further trial I found that the issue from the very beginning had nothing to do with transactions, rather it required me to further deconstruct the json object as the database doesn't accept it for some reason.

here it is working on the orignal code with some edits:

```
app.put("/admin/staff", async (req, res) => {
    // const client = await pool.connect()
    try {
        console.log(req.body)
        const {adminstration } = await req.body
        const {admin_name, admin_email, admin_password} = adminstration
        const newadminstration = await pool.query("INSERT INTO adminstration (admin_name, admin_email, admin_password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *", [admin_name, admin_email, admin_password]);
        return res.json(newadminstration.rows[0]);
    }
     catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
   }
});
```